# sql coalesce not working with group by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, coalesce

I have a table like:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | bob  | k     |
|  2 | kate | NULL  |
|  3 | bob  | NULL  |
|  4 | kate | w     |
+----+------+-------+
```

And I want the following output:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | bob  | k     |
|  2 | kate | W     |
+----+------+-------+
```

when  use coalesce like:

```
select id,name,coalesce(value) from hey group by name;
```

the output is:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | bob  | k     |
|  2 | kate | NULL  |
+----+------+-------+
```

How can I achieve the desired output? please

Answer (score 0):

You want aggregation, but you need to construct it correctly:

```
select min(id) as id, name, max(value)
from hey
group by name;
```

"Correctly" means that all non-aggregated columns should be the arguments to argument functions such as `max()` or `min()`.